# Riding Lawn Mower running very loud

Tags: engine

Can any DIYers tell me why my 2008 Troy Bilt Kohler engine would be running extremely loud and I mean loud, it does run constantly, but very very loud?  What should I check?  I did check the muffler and one bold is missing and the other was loose, so I have ordered the replacement and a new seal to start.  However, when I tightened down the other bolt it did not resolve the issue.

Comment: You need both bolts and the gasket. Don't over-tighten one or you could strip the threads!

Comment: Also you know much of the noise from a mower comes from the mower deck.  And always wear hearing protection on a mower!

Comment: Thank you @Harper I will start wearing my shooting hearing protection.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I am patiently waiting for the new bolt and gasket and have only hand tighted.  Thank you for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

Things that might be the issue here:

1) Muffler is rusted out and no muffling as it should.
2) The gasket between the engine and the muffler is missing or compromised.
3) There are other loose bolts, perhaps the head bolts or the spark plug.  Either of which can allow compression to leak out and be quite loud.

I suspect you'll have some success with your replacement muffler.

Comment: I will add the new gasket and screw and if that does not fix it I will buy the muffler, but it is going for $90.00.   And I just bought a new car so the neighbors will just need to deal with it until I get my budget back in order.